# Migrate off Global HTTP Batch Endpoints - indirect usage

Tags: google-api

I have received an email from Google stating "We are writing to let you know that the JSON-RPC and Global HTTP batch endpoints will be deprecated on March 26, 2018", and that the "HTTP Global batch endpoint" is in use in one of my projects.

However I have no code in that project which directly uses the http batch endpoint. I presume some google library I am using is calling it indirectly, so my question is: how can I figure out which library needs updating, and how can I know when I have managed to resolve the issue?

I use primarily Google Dataflow (v2.3.0), including the TextIO.Write method (java) to write files, and the BigQueryIO method to import data into BigQuery. Could either of those be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The email you received should have explicitly listed both the project id and the API(s) called from that project which will be impacted by the deprecation.

If you received a follow up email with a project id listed but with blank columns titled 'API called' and 'JSON-RPC or Global HTTP Batch Endpoint?', you can safely ignore the email.

If you received something different can you please share the text, redacting any personal information?

Google Dataflow is not *directly* impacted by this deprecation but it does hit the batch endpoint under the hood.  The Dataflow team is aware and will be releasing an updated SDK in due course.

Thanks!

Comment: I too had a second email sent through to me that just showed just the project id and the other columns blanked.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle you can safely disregard the second email.

Comment: Email included a table with:
  ProjectID = ... 
  "API Called" = bigstore@v1
  "JSON-RPC or Global HTTP Batch Endpoint?" = GLOBALBATCH
However I know all code that is executed in this project, and none of it uses the "global batch" api directly. I would _guess_ that we are using some google library that uses global-batch internally - but no idea which. Any idea about how to figure out what to change is welcome!

Comment: Hi Simon, I'm following this up - will get back to you ASAP.

Comment: Dataflow does in fact hit the batch endpoint under the hood.  The Dataflow team will be addressing this and will release an updated SDK in due course.

Comment: I also received a 2nd email with the blank columns, however, I am using the endpoint www.googleapis.com/batch

which I read we should change to

www.googleapis.com/batch/<api>/<version>

But I don't know what the values for api or version should be?

Reference:
https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/discontinuing-support-for-json-rpc-and.html

Comment: @Jason, the API and version should be in the first email you received but the API name and version can also be found the in the discovery document(s) for the API(s) you are calling in the batch. Look for the 'batchPath' value in the discovery doc.

Comment: @danoscarmike I also received this email for API Version `storage@v1`, using the Global HTTPS Batch Endpoint. I suspect Dataflow is the culprit in my case, but I'm only using the Cloud PubSub to GCS Text https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/provided-templates#cloudpubsubtogcstext template. What is the recommended course of action if I'm relying on a template?

Comment: Can you please try upgrading to Dataflow SDK 2.5 or later. This is a known issue that has been fixed in later versions.

Comment: @chamikara I want to try this, but am concerned I'll lose messages from Pub Sub during the upgrade. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52934591/please-migrate-off-json-rpc-and-global-http-batch-endpoints-dataflow-template for details.