# Please migrate off JSON-RPC and Global HTTP Batch Endpoints - Dataflow Template

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I received an email with the Title ^ as the subject. Says it all. I'm not directly using the specified endpoint (storage@v1). The project in question is a postback catcher that funnels data into BigQuery

`App Engine > Pub Sub > Dataflow > Cloud Storage > BigQuery`

Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49549969/migrate-off-global-http-batch-endpoints-indirect-usage) indicates Dataflow might be indirectly using it. I'm only using the Cloud PubSub to GCS Text [template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/provided-templates#cloudpubsubtogcstext).

What is the recommended course of action if I'm relying on a template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the warning may come from a dataflow job which uses the old version of storage API. Please upgrade Dataflow/Beam SDK version beyond 2.5.

Since you're using our PubsubToText template. The easiest way to to it would be:

1. Stop your pipeline. Be sure to select "Drain" when asked.
2. Relaunch the pipeline using the newest version (which is automatically done if you're using UI), from the same subscription.
3. Check the SDK version. It should be at least 2.7.

After that you should not see any more warnings.

Comment: according to PubSub docs "...a message published to a topic with no subscription cannot be retrieved." Wouldn't stopping the pipeline result in a period of time where there are no subscribers to that topic (this is the only subscriber/processor for that topic), and subsequently I'd lose any messages that are published between steps 1) and 2)?

Comment: Set up a test in a new project and confirmed the behavior that the docs specify (lose messages that are published to a topic with no subscribers). I set up a temporary flow to catch anything that came in while updating my main one then manually transferred that data into my dataset. Stopping then starting a new Job did indeed update the SDK. Thanks!